# Found leaks by adding views in interface builder

Tags: iphone, uiview, memory-leaks

I am adding views in interface builder, When i pop my view, There is a huge leak found, When i delete all the views  exept main view then no leaks i found. I am using navigation base application and on button clik , i apply animation like slide up but when i pop the main view i foound leaks.....
in viewdidload:

```
myControlView.hidden    =   YES;//view1
alertView.hidden        =   YES;//view 2/
```

/

On button clik this animation called not every time...

```
myControlView.frame   = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480); // use real numbers
        [myMainView addSubview:myControlView];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        myControlView.frame   = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

two more views i add and apply same thing and i remove view 1 by 1 but leaks still there, How can i remove these leaks?

Note: not every time these functions call ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myControlView.frame   = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480); // use real numbers
       ** [myMainView addSubview:myControlView];**
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        myControlView.frame   = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

remove this line :
**[myMainView addSubview:myControlView];**

Answer (score 0):

the UIView addSubview: method retains the subview.  if that isn't balanced at some point by a call to the removeFromSuperview: method, which releases the subview, then there'll be a memory leak.

Comment: Where i am ussing addSubview?

Answer (score 0):

Build and analyze to check and post the exact line in your code

Comment: Where i am ussing addSubview?

Answer (score 0):

pistachionut is right... AND you shouldn't use addSubview because you already add them in interface builder

Comment: Where i am ussing addSubview?

Comment: [myMainView addSubview:myControlView];